# Convert string to any other type as per input in python

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, tuples

The `input()` methods always return a string. But I want to get any type of object user wants to provide and then work on it.

It is undefined what type of object user wants to provide. It can be a list, tuple, dictionary, or anything.
I want to convert the return string to the type which user wants to provide.

One way I can do this is if the string starts with `[` and ends with `]` then convert it to list and so on for tuple `()`, dictionary `{}`, etc.

There are many other methods or in general which return string but sometimes I don't want it as only string.

Is there any other elegant way to do this?

Comment: "It can be list, tuple, dictionary or anything" What is the rule that will tell you what it is, and how to convert it? And why do you want to do this?

Comment: `input()` is meant for *user* input. If your user knows Python, make a library with functions that your user can call on the objects they want. I cannot think of any circumstance where you would want to `input()` python code. On the other hand, if you want to restrict to certain kinds of brackets only (rather than "anything"), you have to parse them manually. Evaluating user `input` as Python code should be a red flag in most contexts where you have users (as opposed to yourself, who knows Python and can call functions on objects)

Comment: please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`.

```
import ast

ast.literal_eval(input())
```

> [**`ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) Safely evaluate an
> expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container
> display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following
> Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists,
> dicts, sets, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
> values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
> oneself.

**Note:** It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works fine except if the string is a literal string. I can surely solve this by `try` and `except` but I don't think catching a `ValueError` is a good thing. Moreover I came over a method called `eval` which does the same but same problem exists. Would you suggest anything for that?  Thanks!

Comment: why do you think catching `ValueError` will not be good thing?

Answer (score 0):

Most elegant method I would use for the same would be [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)